# Independence groups and fully connected groups

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

Let G be a connected graph, knowing that it has more than 9 vertex, Show that either its independence number is bigger-equal than 4 or its click number (the size of the biggest fully connected group) is bigger-equal than 3.

Comment: It's spelled *clique*. Also, you can use *at least*.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, so I won't give an answer outright (unless that's okay on this site). But you're going to want to suppose that one of those conditions is false (e.g. suppose that the clique number is less than 3) and show that this implies that the other is true (e.g. prove that the independence number is greater than 3).

Comment: @Draconis It is common on this site to only provide hints to these questions. See also the [homework policy](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy/470#470) and [this discussion on homework questions.](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151)

Comment: You don't really need $G$ to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove by induction the following more general claim:

> Let $a,b \geq 1$. Every graph on $\binom{a+b-2}{a-1}$ vertices contains either an independent set of size $a$ or a clique of size $b$.

The proof is by induction. If $a=1$ or $b=1$, then the claim is trivial, so suppose that $a,b>1$. Consider an arbitrary vertex $v$ in the graph. Since
$$ \binom{a+b-2}{a-1} - 1 > \binom{(a-1)+b-2}{(a-1)-1} - 1 + \binom{a+(b-1)-2}{a-1} - 1,$$
one of the following cases must hold:

1. $v$ is not connected to at least $\binom{(a-1)+b-2}{(a-1)-1}$ vertices.
2. $v$ is connected to at least $\binom{a+(b-1)-2}{a-1}$ vertices.

In the first case, induction shows that among the vertices that $v$ is not connected to, we can find either an independent set of size $a-1$ or a clique of size $b$. In the former case, we add $v$ to obtain an independent set of size $a$. In the latter case, we are done.

In the second case, induction shows that among the vertices connected to $v$, we can find either an independent set of size $a$ or a clique of size $b-1$. In the former case, we are done. In the latter case, we add $v$ to obtain a clique of size $b$.

---

Plugging $a=4$ and $b=3$, we calculate $\binom{a+b-2}{a-1} = \binom{5}{3} = 10$. Hence every graph on 10 vertices contains either an independent set of size 4 or a clique of size 3.

---

The topic of this question is known as [Ramsey theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory), a major topic in combinatorics with various applications to several areas of mathematics. The claim proved above is one form of [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem). It is not known what is the minimal number that can replace $\binom{a+b-2}{a-1}$ in the claim. The optimal number is called the [Ramsey number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers) $R(a,b)$.